# Selenium-Java:Browsermob Proxyy- NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy

I updated POM.xml with latest selenium-java dependency and Browsermob proxy.

Java Code:

> ```
>    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
>     driver.get("http://www.google.com");
>     driver.quit();
> ```
>
> POM.xml looks like,

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-8</version>
    </dependency>
```

While I run the automation script, getting the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices`

The script runs fine , after removing Browsermob proxy dependency. ( But I need Browsermob proxy to capture network data).

Looks like the Browsermob proxy has a dependency `selenium-api-2.*`, I assume that is outdated and causing this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked that selenium server and browsermob proxy is up and running before running the script.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a very old version of BrowserMob Proxy, which probably isn't compatible with the latest versions of Selenium.You can find the latest version of BMP on its [github page](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#getting-started-embedded-mode).

For example, the current version of BMP is 2.1.2, so you'd want to include this in your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
    <!-- note the new artifactId -->
    <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```